# Writing conditional equations with braces in sphinx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, cases, sphinx

I want to write conditional statement with one-sided curly brackets in Sphinx as shown below:

[image]

In Latex, the best I could do is given below:

```
\[
x = \begin{cases}
        \begin{split}
            d&,               &     I_x &\leq I_p - t \\
            s&, \; \; I_p - t &\leq I_x &\leq I_p + t \\
            b&, \; \; I_p + t &\leq I_x
        \end{split}
    \end{cases}
\]
```

But it provides some blank spaces in middle of condition (marked in red) as shown below:

[image]

But even that also, doesn't work in Sphinx. It ends up in big error.

**So how can I achieve it in both Latex and Sphinx?**

Answer (score 4):

For LaTeX I'd use an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\[
x =
\left\{
\begin{array}{
  @{}% no padding
  l@{\quad}% some padding
  r@{}% no padding
  >{{}}r@{}% no padding
  >{{}}l@{}% no padding
}
  d,&         &     I_x &\leq I_p - t \\
  s,& I_p - t &\leq I_x &\leq I_p + t \\
  b,& I_p + t &\leq I_x
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

If the center terms of the inequalities don't have the same width, more alignment points are needed to make them centered.

[image]

We don't want any of the automatic padding between colums that `array` usually inserts, so between columns (and also at the start and end of the array) I put `@{}` that disables the insertion. Exception: between the first and second column we want some space.

The mysterious `>{{}}` bit is readily explained: when TeX is doing the second and third column in the second row, it would essentially do

```
$I_p-t$$\leq I_x$
```

because it treats each cell as a separate formula. This doesn't give the correct spacing, so we insert `{}` at the start of the cells in the third column and the final result is

```
$I_p-t$${}\leq I_x$
```

which typesets exactly like

```
$I_p-t\leq I_x$
```

and the desired outcome is obtained.

Comment: +1 - That looks great! Can you tell me about the part of code where you added some comments on padding? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

For Sphinx, you can use directly @egreg's solution,

```
.. math::
   :nowrap:

   \[
   x =
   \left\{
   \begin{array}{
     @{}% no padding
     l@{\quad}% some padding
     r@{}% no padding
     >{{}}r@{}% no padding
     >{{}}l@{}% no padding
   }
     d,&         &     I_x &\leq I_p - t \\
     s,& I_p - t &\leq I_x &\leq I_p + t \\
     b,& I_p + t &\leq I_x
   \end{array}
   \right.
   \]
```

and make sure your `conf.py` loads extension `sphinx.ext.imgmath` (or `.mathjax`: either one or the other is needed for math directive, but the LaTeX file will simply inherit the code as above and PDF output will work as with hand-written LaTeX source).

#### HTML with `imgmath`

You need to add `imgmath_latex_preamble = r'\usepackage{array}'` to your `conf.py` (and of course load `sphinx.ext.imgmath` extension).

[image]

For `svg` rather than `png`, add `imgmath_image_format = 'svg'` to `conf.py`.

#### HTML with `MathJax`

I don't know how to do that. There does not seem to be a contributed `array.js` extension to MathJax. There is `siunitx.js`. As a LaTeX package it requires `array`, but this does not at all mean that the `siunitx.js` implements `array` syntax ...

For more info:

- http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-extensions
- https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions

As there does not seem to be a MathJax solution I could identify, even when editing manually the HTML file, I have not looked too closely into how to get the extra `<script>` tags.